# WP 4.8 : new taxonomy syntax for get_term_by and get_term_link ?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

After migrate from WP 4.7.5 to WP 4.8,

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug','travaux', "rubriques" ); echo $term->name;?>
```

work fine in WP 4.7.5 but empty result in WP 4.8

and

```
<?php echo get_term_link("bibliotheques","rubriques"); ?>
```

work fine in WP 4.7.5 but empty result in WP 4.8

Wath's news in (custom) taxonomy syntax ? 
I did'nt found anythings about this subject....
A solution would be greatly appreciated..
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely unlikely for such major part API to be changed in WP release. It is likely that something got broken in your install (possibly unconnected to upgrade) and it needs hands on debug.

First steps would be something like:

- stepping through lower level functions and checking returns, at some point you might get to a more telling `WP_Error` return
- examining database for data presence/sanity and need of repair

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions
But my problem is very strange.
I updated my website to WP 4.8
After, if I downgrade * only * the file "taxonomy.php", everything is OK! The website is fully fonctionaly. 
But If I keep taxonomy.php (wp 4.8), website bug in line code wich call function ".get_term_by(" and "get_term_link("

Comment: Possible you got file corrupted for some reason, get a clean copy from 4.8 distribution and see if it's different to what you have.